# How to access specific raw data on SD card?

Tags: java, android

I am doing an Android project. In this project i need to read the data of SD card sector by sector.I tried in some ways , Like

```
RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile("\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0","r");
```

But Filenotfound Exception is coming. I did a similar kind of project in MFC(VC++). There by using Handle, CreateFile nad ReadFile functions i am reading the data sector wise. Any functions are there in java to read the data sector by sector ?

Comment: How where you running MFC on Android?  Do you even have root access of Android?

Answer (score 0):

To read the SD card sector by sector, you'll need to run as root.  I'd suggest something like the following:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c dd if=/dev/mmcblk1 of=/dev/stdout");
```

This should return a `Process` object whose standard output stream contains the data.  The device name of the SD card may vary between different systems, and AFAIK there is no standardized way of finding out what it is, so you will have to experiment a little.

Good luck. :)

Answer (score 0):

Jules is right if you read a block device,
however the internal storage in the new systems is mounted(exec mount on the device to check) on /mnt/shell/emulated(or smth like this) from /dev/fuse(using fuse daemon), which is not a block device but a [character device( character special file)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file#Character_devices), meaning that you cannot use random access to get data.
check out [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/sdcard/sdcard.c), it might help.

Answer (score -1):

You want to read data from sd card.So do something like this..

```
File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File yourFile = new File(dir, "path_of_your_file");
```

And then you can read the file like..

```
fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(yourFile);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream));
String readString = new String();
while((readString = br.readLine())!= null){
   //readString has your data
}
```